# Chaining Observable Subscriptions

Tags: .net, system.reactive

Is there a shorthand version of this.  I want to call one sequence and then when it is finished call another.

```
var seq1 = Observable.Range(1, 20);
var seq2 = Observable.Range(21, 20);

seq1.Subscribe(
    i  => Console.WriteLine(i), 
    () => seq2.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine(i)));
```

Comment: I was doing something similar and expected exceptions in the inner subscription bit me until I came up with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769602/self-error-dependent-self-disposal-of-iobservable-subscriptions/11770674#11770674. Wonder if you have had such an issue yourself, or know of a different, perhaps built-in way to stop observer exceptions bubbling all the way up to observables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to do (and I don't have the docs to hand) but is Observables.Concat what you're after?

```
var seq1 = Observable.Range(1, 20);
var seq2 = Observable.Range(21, 20);
var both = seq1.Concat(seq2);
both.Subscribe(i => Console.WriteLine(i));
```

(I'm just checking that this actually works :)

Comment: Since he has 20 as the end of seq1 and 21 the start of seq2 then Concat is correct.

Comment: Not trying to do anything but get 2 observables to execute one after another.  This appears to do what I want in this case but what if the 2 observables where different types?

Comment: @kouPhax: I'm not entirely sure how you'd want to use that. Could you give an example of what you'd *want* to be able to write?

Comment: To be honest that's it.... rather than any real world scenario I was writing some small Linq 101 style examples and was wondering if it was possible to chain Observables based on OnComplete firing.  There is probably no real world application as you say but it just made me think.

Thanks for the response.

Comment: What about two async observables that pass the result of the first async result on to the second async result.  Doesn't seem like concat would help in that situation. :-/

Comment: @NormanH: I think you'd need to give more details (possibly in a new question) for me to say, to be honest. (Partly due to me having a cold, which is fogging up my thinking.)