# Self-error-dependent self-disposal of IObservable subscriptions

Tags: .net, exception, f#, system.reactive, combinators

I have F# code that looks like this:

```
module O = Control.Observable
//...
use ss = serve' 4000
         |> O.subscribe
            (fun c -> use cs = RSS.items
                               |> O.subscribe (bytes >> c.SendAll) |> ignore)
```

---

where

```
serve'    : int -> IObservable<Socket>
c         : Socket
RSS.items : IObservable<XElement>
bytes     : XElement -> byte []
c.SendAll : byte [] -> unit
```

- What is the most idiomatic way to retain `cs` until `c.SendAll` fails?
- Is there or is it possible to define **`Observable.subscribeUntilError(action)`** where if `action` fails, subscription gets disposed; otherwise `action` is run as long as `IObservable` keeps pushing?

Comment: Subscriptions automatically get disposed when the observable completes by either "OnComplete" or "OnError". You only ever need to dispose of the subscription if you want early termination.

Comment: @Enigmativity Oh and do they *stick around* if not explicitly disposed but only gone out of scope? That would explain why `ignore` seems to not leave them to garbage collection and why my above code kind of works.

Comment: They are just like any .NET object - if they go out of scope and there are no references left to them then they will be GC'ed.

Comment: @Enigmativity I have just extended my answer to show the problem I was trying to solve with an example. It is difficult for me to formulate stuff precisely as I am pretty new-born to the whole reactive business and cannot speak the terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with this:

```
let inline Δ<'a> = Unchecked.defaultof<'a>
let inline LOG x = printf "%A" x

module O = Observable
  let d = ref (Δ:IDisposable)
  let b x = try a x with e -> LOG e; let s = !d in if s <> Δ then s.Dispose()
  d := o |> O.subscribe b
  {
    new IDisposable with
      member x.Dispose() = let s = !d in if s <> Δ then d := Δ; s.Dispose()
  }
```

---

To demonstrate the difference, try in `main`!

**Using `subscribe`**:

```
use s = new Subject<int>()
use x = s |> O.subscribe (fun _ -> raise <| Exception ())
use y = s |> O.subscribe (printf "%i")
s.OnNext 20
```

application comes crashing down:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Exception: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators.Raise[T](Exception exn)
   at Program.System.x@604-5.Invoke(Int32 _arg1) in C:\Eniox\Eniox.News.Google\Eniox.News.Google\Program.fs:line 60
   at Microsoft.FSharp.Control.CommonExtensions.SubscribeToObservable@1915.System-IObserver`1-OnNext(T value)
   at System.Reactive.Observer`1.OnNext(T value)
   at System.Reactive.Subjects.Subject`1.OnNext(T value)
   at Program.System.main(String[] args) in C:\Eniox\Eniox.News.Google\Eniox.News.Google\Program.fs:line 606
```

---

**Now using `subscribeUE`**:

```
use s = new Subject<int>()
use x = s |> O.subscribeUE (fun _ -> raise <| Exception ())
use y = s |> O.subscribe   (printf "%i")
s.OnNext 20
```

delightfully disposes subscription `x`, application continues to run without a hiccup and exits normally! Output *with* `LOG = ignore`:

```
20
```

---

I would love to know whether comparable functionality actually exists somewhere in RX 2.0 as I find this combinator to be too useful to leave out.